# VBA set charts on multiple sheets invisible Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have about 9 different sheets, but they all will have 4 types of graphs (totals, comparison, bydate, trend). I am writing VBA to conditionally show one type of graph on every sheet. For example, if I want to show the totals graphs, I want all of my sheets in the workbook to update. I can already make the graphs go invisible and visible on one sheet, but I would like to do so on all sheets. Here's my code now:

```
Sub UpdateGraph()
 Sheets(".graphManager").ChartObjects("Totals").Visible = False
End Sub
```

I want to be able to do this on all sheets so I tried something like this:

```
Sub UpdateGraph()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
       If ws.Visible Then ws.Select (False)
         ActiveWorksheet.ChartObjects("Totals").Visible = False
    Next
End Sub
```

But no luck. I do not want to manually type all the sheet names into an array because I may add more sheets in the future and don't want to keep changing the code. How can I loop through all sheets and set a graph named "Totals" to invisible? Or can I just set all graphs in the workbook named "Totals" to invisible without looping through the sheets? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass in a parameter that determines which graph should be visible each time.  Then at the time you are selecting the graph type, you can call the function once, pass in the selected graph type, and it will turn that graph on and all others off, across all your sheets.

```
Sub UpdateGraph(graphType As String)
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        For Each co In ws.ChartObjects
            '''Turn off all charts on the sheet first'''
            ws.ChartObjects(co.Name).Visible = False
        Next
        '''Turn on the one chart type we want'''
        ws.ChartObjects(graphType).Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! I did find a similar solution on my own, but yours was even better.

Comment: why `ws.ChartObjects(co.Name).Visible = False` and not just `co.Visible = False`? Otherwise, straight to the point.

Comment: Eh, I just didn't think of it as I was banging out an example.  The way I did it is consistent with the way I turned the other chart back on so I just stuck with it.

Comment: You can just use `co.Visible = (co.Name = graphType)` in your loop.